# Marquee not happening after scroll

Tags: html, css

Hi I tried to have a marquee gif on my website. And the gif only happens when u don't move your mouse for 4 secs. But I can't seem to figure out why this only happens when you land on the page, but when you start scrolling the marquee gif doesnt happen.

Check it out on my [website](http://shutianchan.com) here. Any help is deeply appreciated.Thank you

```
<marquee behavior=scroll direction=down scrollamount=2 scrolldelay=29 height=582 style='position:absolute; left:48%; top:57px; width:32; height:582px;'> <img src=http://transit7.cargocollective.com/1/8/265975/3801686/icecream.gif border=0> </marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScriptyou have:

```
      $('html').mousemove(100, function() {
        $('#hi').fadeOut(400);
    });
```

This is the cause - it basically means "If you move the mouse over the <html> element (which is anywhere on the whole page) then fadeout the specified stuff (in the #hi div)". And mousemove includes moving the mouse to scroll.

Comment: hi @GuyH thanks for your reply. But what i meant, is that when you scroll to the bottom of the page of each project, and wait for the marquee gif to happen, it doesn't happen. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh I see what you're after now. There's a difference in browsers here - what browser are you using?. In IE11 it does what you want, the gifs appear after a few seconds (but the scroll bar is back at the top). In Firefox the gifs don't reappear at all. Chrome differs again - mousing over the right scrollbar doesn't hide the gifs - unlike IE and Firefox where mousing over the scrollbar behaves the same as mousing over the display. I don't know why they differ. But maybe this gives you a bit more info to put into a new question, directed at experts on browser differences maybe.